# Routing controller / action PHP

Tags: model-view-controller, controller, routes, url-routing

I want create a Routing how in Cakephp/Laravel/etc...Them I can do routing a controller, action and params, like this:

```
/mycontroller/myaction/param1/param2
```

However, I not know how to do this in PHP. My purpose is to uses in RESTful.

Thanks....